# concatenating .java files in java

Tags: java

so I'm making a java app to find all java files on a directory and then concatenate them into one single file to be put on the same directory but I can't seem to get the concatenation right. Here's what I've done so far hope you guys can help me with it as I've tried various things but still can't get it right. Thanks!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileConcatenate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirName = args[0];
        String fileName = args[1];
        File dirFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\" + dirName + "");
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\" + dirName + "\\" + fileName + ".java");
        FileFilter filter = new FileFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File pathname){
                if(pathname.getName().contains(".java")){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
        try{
            if(!dirFile.exists()){
                System.out.println("There is no directory with that name");
            }
            File[] javaFile = dirFile.listFiles(filter);
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            for(File f : javaFile){
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
                fw.write(fr.read());
                fr.close();
            }
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `but I can't seem to get the concatenation right` Why not? What is going wrong?

Comment: Reading the javadoc helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28%29

Comment: Start at the basics, read the contents of one file and write it to another file.

Comment: you are going to get the first character of each file concatenated. Not the entire contents...

Comment: Note: You can only have one top level public class in a Java file.  You could have an interface at the top level and have any number of public classes inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do in this way. For more info read inline comments.

```
...
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
for (File f : javaFile) {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    // read 1000 chars at a time from source file
    char[] cbuf = new char[1000];
    int count = -1;
    // iterate till the end of source file
    // here count represent the no of chars read at a time
    while ((count = fr.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
        // write in the targeted file
        fw.write(cbuf, 0, count);
    }
    fr.close();
}
...
```

---

In your case `fw.write(fr.read());` doesn't do what you are expecting.

It just read one character form the source file and write in the target file.

For more info have a look at [InputStreamReader#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28%29) that **reads a single character**.

Comment: ahh yea this works, thanks alot! I will read more about streams for now